# Removing index entry from Google mini box

Tags: episerver, google-search-appliance

We've taken over the support of an EPiServer (5 R2) website (.NET) that uses a Google Mini (no longer offered) to display search results on their site.

Unlike lots of other search solutions, especially those built for EPiServer, the Google mini box indexes the content of the website by crawling the website's URL's - whereas other solutions hook into EPiServers PagePublished, PageDeleted event and accept data to store in the index. The problem the client has been encountering is that when a Page/Document is deleted from EPiServer, it is not immediately deleted from the index on the Google mini box. Therefore for a period of time the deleted page is still returned in the search results - this poses a problem because at times the client must remove pages/documents for legal reasons and therefore the removal needs to be immediate.

The Google mini box does allow the entry of url's that should be indexed more frequently than others, but even so this will not be immediate.

Can anyone advise whether there are programmatical methods available to work with i.e. a HTTP DELETE request? Or any other solutions you may have found in the past?

Many thanks
dotdev

Comment: Looks like there's no way to force Google Mini to remove URL immediately from index, so you need to find some workaround. I think most obvious is to hook search results page, check every URL for existence with EPiServer (+ FilterForVisitor), and remove such URLs which exist in index but nomore available for user from search results. In worst case users will receive say 5 hits per page instead of 10, but at least they won't see broken link.

Comment: Hi @Lanorkin - I had thought the same thing. The problem is, the Google mini box returns the entire HTML i.e. on the Google Mini box there is a XSLT template setup so that when results are returned the HTML is already generated. You simply then embed the HTML into your page. Therefore you have no access to an individual result..bit of a mare! Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Maybe I confuse google mini with google desktop, but I believe there was possibility to receive XML result, which you can preprocess (in your case - remove nodes for 404 URLs) and then use XSLT to create HTML for user. Otherwise, how are results integrated into frontend page? Is it iframe to google service, or is it HTML which you can postprocess?